# Formula (Text) Field is not working as expected

Tags: formula, formula-field

I created a **Formula (Text)** Field for changing **Elapsed Time to HH:MM:SS** Format in **cases** with below code

```
IF(NOT(ISNULL(TEXT(On_Hold_Start_Time__c ))), 
Text(FLOOR((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR(((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24))* 60)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR((((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 - FLOOR(((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((On_Hold_Start_Time__c - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 )) * 60 )), 


IF(NOT(ISNULL( TEXT(Reopen_DateTime__c ))), 
Text(FLOOR((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR(((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24))* 60)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR((((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24 )) * 60 - FLOOR(((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - Reopen_DateTime__c) * 24 )) * 60 )) * 60 )), 


IF(Text(Status) == "Closed", 
Text(FLOOR((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR(((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24))* 60)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR((((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 - FLOOR(((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((SlaExitDate - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 )) * 60 )), 


IF(NOT(ISNULL( TEXT(SlaStartDate ))), 
Text(FLOOR((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR(((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24))* 60)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR((((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 - FLOOR(((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - SlaStartDate) * 24 )) * 60 )) * 60 )), 


Text(FLOOR((now() - CreatedDate) * 24)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR(((now() - CreatedDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - CreatedDate) * 24))* 60)) 
&":"&Text(FLOOR((((now() - CreatedDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - CreatedDate) * 24 )) * 60 - FLOOR(((now() - CreatedDate) * 24 - FLOOR((now() - CreatedDate) * 24 )) * 60 )) * 60 ))))))
```

But it's worked for only **On Hold** (On_Hold_Start_Time__c(***First IF condition Block***)) cases why it's executing only first 5 Lines of code why it's not coming to below conditions (like for Reopen , closed , ...)

Please kindly suggest me

Comment: Try using isblank instead of isnull as iirc text either returns a value or an empty string not null. Thus the first part will Always evaluate to true

Answer (score 1):

Use `ISBLANK` instead of `ISNULL` as  `TEXT` either returns a value or an empty string not null. Thus the first part will Always evaluate to true

`IF(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT(On_Hold_Start_Time__c ))).........`

And change `ISNULL` to `ISBLANK` everywhere you are using `TEXT`

Comment: Many thanks for the prompt reply , ya i replaced all ISNULL with ISBLANK  Function but it showing an Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Compiled formula is too big to execute (22,082 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters (Related field: Formula)

Comment: That's a different problem that require you to do a bit of searching as there is lots of good info here about that. For your question though this answer explains the why of your question